# Need help to create div structure

Tags: html

I want to create div structure as I have attached image. Please anyone can help me out for the same.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do ? Is it about the rounded corners and drop shadow ?

Comment: What have you tried? Could do it for a few. There are plenty of tutorials on-line to get you started.

Comment: um... are you trying to get the div in the center of the screen?

Comment: I want only structure like image using HTML nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like below and position them by float

```
<div class='outer'>
<div class='left'></div>
<div class='tow'>
   <div class='up'></div>
     <div class='cbt'></div>
   <div class='jimit'></div>
     <div class='one'></div>
   <div class='below'></div>
</div>
<div class='right'></div>
```

css

```
.outer,leftm.right,.tow{float:left;}
.left,.right{width:25%;}
.tow{width:50%;}
.cbt{clar:both}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use position absolute for this - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xV28x/)

```
.center {
   position: absolute;
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin-left: -150px; /* Half of div width */
   margin-top: -100px; /* Half of div height */
}
```